# MySqlDb throws Operand should contain 1 column(s) on insert ignore statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, executemany

While looking at some of the websocket methods that stack exchange offers, I wanted to save a few data points into a MySQL database. However, when I attempt to run an `executemany` command, I get the following error:

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

While looking around SO, I found many examples of this error, but they have dealt with removing parenthesis on `SELECT` statements. I'm not using a `SELECT`. I'm attempting to `INSERT`.

A short, contained, example of my code looks like this:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
db = mdb.connect(host='localhost',user='myuser',db='qs',passwd='mypass',use_unicode=True,charset='utf8')
cur = db.cursor()
db_qry = """INSERT IGNORE INTO questions (id, site_base, title, body_sum, tags, last_act_dt, url, owner_url, owner, api_site) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""


parms = [(u'mathematica.stackexchange.com', 
43248, 
u'How to plot &ldquo;Normalized distance&rdquo; in this problem', 
u"Problem: there are two particles whose equationsof motion both satisfy -n Abs[x[t]]^n/x[t] == x''[t]. But their initial conditions are different: one is x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 2;another is x'[0] == 0, ...", 
[u'plotting', u'equation-solving', u'differential-equations', u'numerical-integration', u'notebooks'],
1393801095,
u'http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/how-to-plot-normalized-distance-in-this-problem',
u'http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12706/lawerance', u'Lawerance', u'mathematica')]

cur.executemany(db_qry, parms)
cur.commit()
```

Am I using the `executemany` incorrect? Or missing another aspect of the `parms` list that I need to clean before passing to `executemany`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was the data going into the `tags` column. It was attempting to pass a list instead of a string.

For the sample in my original question, I used this code to convert it to a string.

```
','.join([u'plotting', u'equation-solving', u'differential-equations', u'numerical-integration', u'notebooks'])
```

It should also be noted that I messed up my commit line. It should be `db.commit()` not `cur.commit()`

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem while trying to save a df with a column of lists to mysql via `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` which can automate some of this process. Instead of using `join`, I typically convert the lists to encoded strings using `json.dumps()`. The `json` package also makes it easy to load it all back in to its original format with `json.loads()`.

In the case of the original example I would convert `parms` to a dataframe

```
parms = pd.DataFrame(parms)
parms
                               0      1  \
0  mathematica.stackexchange.com  43248

                                                   2  \
0  How to plot &ldquo;Normalized distance&rdquo; ...

                                                   3  \
0  Problem: there are two particles whose equatio...

                                                   4           5  \
0  [plotting, equation-solving, differential-equa...  1393801095

                                                   6  \
0  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions...

                                                   7          8            9
0  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/127...  Lawerance  mathematica
```

Then convert the column of lists to json strings:

```
parms[4] = parms[4].apply(json.dumps)
parms

0  mathematica.stackexchange.com  43248

                                                   2  \
0  How to plot &ldquo;Normalized distance&rdquo; ...

                                                   3  \
0  Problem: there are two particles whose equatio...

                                                   4           5  \
0  ["plotting", "equation-solving", "differential...  1393801095

                                                   6  \
0  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions...

                                                   7          8            9
0  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/127...  Lawerance  mathematica
```

Fire up a MySQL connection (using details provided above):

```
import sqlalchemy
call = 'mysql+mysqldb://myuser:mypass@localhost:3306/qs' 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(call)
```

Then dump it using the built in pandas function:

```
parms.to_sql('questions', engine, if_exists='append', chunksize=5000)
```